# '--link' does not seem to work to connect two Docker containers

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-link

I would like to run MongoDB in a container, this works:

```
docker run -p 27017:27017 --name cdt -d mongo
```

then I want to run a server in another container, like so:

```
docker run --name foo --link cdt:mongo exec /bin/bash -c "node server.js"
```

The node.js server attempts to make a mongodb connection to `localhost:27017`, but it fails to make the connection.

Anyone know why that might happen? Am I not linking the containers correctly?

Note that I can successfully connect to the mongodb container from *outside* a container, but not from the server inside the "foo" container.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So `localhost` from a container is always (99.5% of the time) referring *to the container itself*. This is also 99.5% of the time not what you want. If you're using `links` like this, you need to change `localhost:27017` to `mongo:27017` as that's what you're 'mounting' the link as (`--link cdt:mongo`).

A better option is to use Docker networks instead of links (which are deprecated). So:

```
$ docker network create my-net
$ docker run --name cdt --net my-net -d mongo
$ docker run --name foo --net my-net exec /bin/bash -c "node server.js"
```

Now you'd refer to your db via `cdt:27017` as the names of the containers become resolvable via DNS on the same network. Note that you don't need to expose a port if you're not intending to connect from the outside world, inter-connectivity between containers on the same network doesn't require port mapping.

Comment: thanks!! would it be cdt:27017 or my-net:27017? Why would it be cdt:27017?

Comment: `cdt` as it's the name of the container (`--name cdt`). This name will be added to DNS lookup. You can also add more resolvable names by adding aliases (`--alias`). `my-net` is just the name of the network you're attaching the containers to.

Comment: got it, thanks, I wish it were the name of the network (since that's shared) instead of the name of mongodb container, but I will live

Comment: this saves me 3 year after, amazing!

Comment: You simply saved my day!